# How do I UPDATE (not grow) polyline as car moves - Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I tried Googling my problem but could only find solutions showing how to add points and `grow polyline` as vehicle moves. But I wish to UPDATE the polyline (i,e grow or reduce)

I am implementing a location tracking feature in my app using Google Maps and I'm able to

`-> draw the route between origin & destination`

`-> locate the vehicle on map as a marker`

Now I wish to update the polyline as the vehicle starts moving (i,e polyline's one end should be the `destination` and the other end should be the `marker` indicating the location of the vehicle).

The only way I can think of to updating the `polyline` as the car moves is to re-call the `Directions API` everytime the vehicle's position changes and then recalculate the polyline points and re-set them again.

But would it be the best approach ? Can I do something locally to recalculate the points and update the polyline as the car moves? How do companies like Uber do it?

> This isn't any platform specific problem, I am only asking about the best approach of recalculating polyline points?

Comment: Take a look at [`SphericalUtil.interpolate()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#interpolate-LatLng-LatLng-double-) of  [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko interpolate() is drawing Linear line right? is it possible to follow the direction of road ('overview_polyline' from Directions API) instead of a straight line?

Comment: @SnowBases Yes its possible, because any polyline consists of linear segments. You should apply `interpolate()` to each straight segment.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Well thanks for the input, I have figured out after that, the `interpolate()` location (lat/lng) can be used in `polyline.getPoints().setAt(0, interpolateLocation)` which means 0 at the start of the segment. but if isLocationOnEdge() is returning false, it just need to recall the direction API.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko It has been almost 2 years and trust me there is still no proper example available on the internet. It seems like you are experienced with `SphericalUtil`, could you kindly post a working example as an answer. That would be wonderful.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I look forward to this as well, I've been digging around the web for sometimes now and more over I'm not an Android guy but I hope if I could see how it's been done with SphericalUtil, It'll help a lot.